# Tableadapter will not add to form

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

When I drag a field from a table on the DataSources Window onto a form, the bindingsource is created (shows at bottom above Error List tab). However, the tableadapter is not created. I have tried rebuilding my solution, I have tried saving and closing visual studio and reopening. I've even tried rebooting my computer. I have tried renaming the dataset, inserting a new dataset with the same tables, and naming the new dataset the name of the original dataset. If I try to use the (uncreated) tableadapter in the background, intellisense does not recognize it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

TableAdapter magically appeared on the form after a couple hours

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't answer my question at all.